# What are the differences between these four commands?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

1. `ls -yz 1>&2 2> command.log`

   no output in console, it is in `command.log`
2. `ls -yz 1>&2 1> command.log`

   ```
   ls: invalid option -- 'y'
   Try 'ls --help' for more information.
   ```
3. `ls -yz 2>&1 2> command.log`

   no output in console, it is in `command.log`
4. `ls -yz 2>&1 1> command.log`

   ```
   ls: invalid option -- 'y'
   Try 'ls --help' for more information.
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`ls -yz` only ever produces output on standard error, so as a general rule for these four cases, it doesn't matter what standard output (file descriptor 1) is directed to.

1. Standard error is redirected to `command.log`, so you get the output in there.
2. You redirect standard output twice: first to what standard error is directing to (the console), then to `command.log`, but nothing is written to standard output. The command is equivalent to

   ```sh
   ls -yz > command.log
   ```

   but the redirection doesn't matter, because output is written only to standard error.
3. You redirect standard error twice: first to what standard output is directing to (the console), then to `command.log`. The command is equivalent to

   ```sh
   ls -yz 2> command.log
   ```
4. You redirect standard error to what standard output is directing to (the console), and only then you redirect standard output to `command.log`. Standard error is still redirected to the console.

The Bash Hackers wiki has a pretty good [Redirection Tutorial](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial).